# Using and installing SMSLIB java

Tags: java-me

How do I install smslib for java? What dependencies do I need to sms.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this library isn't a Java ME library.

[form the installation instructions](http://smslib.org/doc/installation/)

To use SMSLib, you should install the following components:

- SUN JDK 1.5 or newer.
- Java Communications Library.
- Apache ANT for building the sources.
- Apache log4j.
- Apache Jakarta Commons - NET.
- JSMPP Library

and off course you need a GSM modem.

But I do prefer to use [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) instead